# Allow EC2 Instances to communicate with the Services of Kubernetes deployments

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubernetes-service

I am trying to get a Windows Server EC2 instance to communicate with a running Kubernetes Service. I do not want to have to route through the internet, as both the EC2 Instance and Service are sitting within a private subnet.

I am able to get communication through when using the private IP address of the Service, but because of the nature of Kubernetes when the Service goes down, for whatever reason, the private IP can change. I want to avoid this if possible.
I either want to communicate with the service using a static private DNS name or some kind of static private IP address I can create and bind to the Service during creation. Is either of this possible to do?

P.S. I have tried looking into internal LoadBalancers, but I can't get it to work. Don't even know if this is the right direction. https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/service/annotations/#traffic-routing. Currently I am using these annotations for EIP binding for some public-facing services.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a kubeconfig to access the EKS services through kubectl?
See documenation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html

or you want to send traffic to the services?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not EC2 instance itself that needs to communicate with the Service, it's actually a couple of proprietary applications installed on the EC2 instance that needs to.

Comment: Try creating an ingress to expose k8s services https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: Perhaps this is what I am looking for. Does ingress require nginx to also be deployed or not?

Comment: There are number of ingress controllers: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/. Nginx is one of them: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/